# syntax for domain name parser

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to get a limited syntax for domain names to work. The syntax is defined at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035 Section 2.3.1. A subset of it is as under

```
<label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]
<ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>
<let-dig-hyp> ::= <let-dig> | "-"
<let-dig> ::= <letter> | <digit>
<letter> ::= any one of the 52 alphabetic characters A through Z in upper case and a through z in lower case
<digit> ::= any one of the ten digits 0 through 9
```

My attempt below. I'm trying to match `label`

```
grammar Domain;

domain: label NEWLINE;
label:  LETDIG (LETDIGHYP+ LETDIG)?;
LETDIGHYP   : (LETDIG|'-');
LDHSTR      : [0-9a-zA-Z-]+;
LETDIG      : [0-9a-zA-Z];
NEWLINE     : [\r\n]+   ;
```

However I get a `line 1:0 mismatched input 'abc123' expecting LETDIG` when trying to match against `abc123`. What's wrong with my syntax ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of those helper rules like  need to be fragment rules. Check out the keyword "antlr fragment rules" and it should get you there.  Any token that is only used to help other tokens, and is not sent back to the parser, is considered a fragment rule.